# Richfaces 3.3.3 fileupload fails - with error: (OS 10054) existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host

Tags: jsf, richfaces, jsf-1.2

We have a setup with Front-end Apache web server for JBoss application server. Our env is Myfaces 1.2.6 with Tomahawk, Ricfaces 3.3.3

Please note that **only from one of our client network**, upload is failing only for **large** file sizes. (**sometimes** fails for above 50-100MB, and **always** fails for above 200MB)

The logs in front-end apache web server shows:

```
 x.x.x.x - - [09/Sep/2012:11:45:49 -0400] "POST /myapp/ui/home.faces HTTP/1.1" 200 4986
 x.x.x.x - - [09/Sep/2012:11:45:50 -0400] "POST /myapp/ui/home.faces HTTP/1.1" 200 4986
 x.x.x.x - - [09/Sep/2012:11:45:51 -0400] "POST /myapp/ui/home.faces HTTP/1.1" 200 4986
 x.x.x.x - - [09/Sep/2012:11:45:17 -0400] "POST /myapp
/ui/home.faces?_richfaces_upload_uid=0.9487435704432351&
actionForm:upload=actionForm:upload&_richfaces_upload_file_indicator=true&
AJAXREQUEST=actionForm:j_id45760 HTTP/1.1" 200 -
```

The error in JBoss AS console is:

```
2012-09-10 12:21:34,796 ERROR [org.apache.myfaces.shared_tomahawk.renderkit.html.HtmlGridRendererBase] (ajp-0.0.0.0-8009-1) Wrong columns attribute for PanelGrid headerTableId: -2147483648
2012-09-10 12:22:21,981 ERROR [org.apache.myfaces.lifecycle.PhaseListenerManager] (ajp-0.0.0.0-8009-2) Exception in PhaseListener RESTORE_VIEW 1 beforePhase.
org.ajax4jsf.exception.FileUploadException: IO Error parsing multipart request
    at org.ajax4jsf.request.MultipartRequest.parseRequest(MultipartRequest.java:388)
    at org.richfaces.component.FileUploadPhaselistener.beforePhase(FileUploadPhaselistener.java:63)
    at org.apache.myfaces.lifecycle.PhaseListenerManager.informPhaseListenersBefore(PhaseListenerManager.java:73)
    at org.apache.myfaces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl.executePhase(LifecycleImpl.java:93)
    at org.apache.myfaces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl.execute(LifecycleImpl.java:76)
    at javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet.service(FacesServlet.java:265)
    at org.apache.myfaces.webapp.MyFacesServlet.service(MyFacesServlet.java:103)

    at com.mycom.myapp.FacesErrorHandlingServlet.service(FacesErrorHandlingServlet.java:44)

    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor580.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
    at org.apache.catalina.security.SecurityUtil$1.run(SecurityUtil.java:275)
    at org.apache.catalina.security.SecurityUtil$1.run(SecurityUtil.java:274)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAsPrivileged(Subject.java:517)
    at org.apache.catalina.security.SecurityUtil.execute(SecurityUtil.java:307)
    at org.apache.catalina.security.SecurityUtil.doAsPrivilege(SecurityUtil.java:167)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:283)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.access$000(ApplicationFilterChain.java:56)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain$1.run(ApplicationFilterChain.java:189)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:185)
    at org.apache.myfaces.webapp.filter.ExtensionsFilter.doFilter(ExtensionsFilter.java:301)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor461.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
    at org.apache.catalina.security.SecurityUtil$1.run(SecurityUtil.java:275)
    at org.apache.catalina.security.SecurityUtil$1.run(SecurityUtil.java:274)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAsPrivileged(Subject.java:517)
    at org.apache.catalina.security.SecurityUtil.execute(SecurityUtil.java:307)
    at org.apache.catalina.security.SecurityUtil.doAsPrivilege(SecurityUtil.java:248)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:230)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.access$000(ApplicationFilterChain.java:56)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain$1.run(ApplicationFilterChain.java:189)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:185)

    at com.mycom.myapp.FacesSessionFilter.process(FacesSessionFilter.java:57)
    at com.mycom.myapp.SessionFilter.doFilter(SessionFilter.java:133)

    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
    at org.apache.catalina.security.SecurityUtil$1.run(SecurityUtil.java:275)
    at org.apache.catalina.security.SecurityUtil$1.run(SecurityUtil.java:274)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAsPrivileged(Subject.java:517)
    at org.apache.catalina.security.SecurityUtil.execute(SecurityUtil.java:307)
    at org.apache.catalina.security.SecurityUtil.doAsPrivilege(SecurityUtil.java:248)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:230)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.access$000(ApplicationFilterChain.java:56)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain$1.run(ApplicationFilterChain.java:189)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:185)
    at org.ajax4jsf.webapp.BaseXMLFilter.doXmlFilter(BaseXMLFilter.java:206)
    at org.ajax4jsf.webapp.BaseFilter.handleRequest(BaseFilter.java:290)
    at org.ajax4jsf.webapp.BaseFilter.processUploadsAndHandleRequest(BaseFilter.java:367)
    at org.ajax4jsf.webapp.BaseFilter.doFilter(BaseFilter.java:515)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor279.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
    at org.apache.catalina.security.SecurityUtil$1.run(SecurityUtil.java:275)
    at org.apache.catalina.security.SecurityUtil$1.run(SecurityUtil.java:274)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAsPrivileged(Subject.java:517)
    at org.apache.catalina.security.SecurityUtil.execute(SecurityUtil.java:307)
    at org.apache.catalina.security.SecurityUtil.doAsPrivilege(SecurityUtil.java:248)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:230)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.access$000(ApplicationFilterChain.java:56)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain$1.run(ApplicationFilterChain.java:189)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:185)
    at org.jboss.web.tomcat.filters.ReplyHeaderFilter.doFilter(ReplyHeaderFilter.java:96)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor254.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
    at org.apache.catalina.security.SecurityUtil$1.run(SecurityUtil.java:275)
    at org.apache.catalina.security.SecurityUtil$1.run(SecurityUtil.java:274)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAsPrivileged(Subject.java:517)
    at org.apache.catalina.security.SecurityUtil.execute(SecurityUtil.java:307)
    at org.apache.catalina.security.SecurityUtil.doAsPrivilege(SecurityUtil.java:248)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:230)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.access$000(ApplicationFilterChain.java:56)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain$1.run(ApplicationFilterChain.java:189)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:185)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:235)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:191)
    at org.jboss.web.tomcat.security.SecurityAssociationValve.invoke(SecurityAssociationValve.java:190)
    at org.jboss.web.tomcat.security.JaccContextValve.invoke(JaccContextValve.java:92)
    at org.jboss.web.tomcat.security.SecurityContextEstablishmentValve.process(SecurityContextEstablishmentValve.java:126)
    at org.jboss.web.tomcat.security.SecurityContextEstablishmentValve.invoke(SecurityContextEstablishmentValve.java:70)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:127)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:102)
    at org.jboss.web.tomcat.service.jca.CachedConnectionValve.invoke(CachedConnectionValve.java:158)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:109)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:330)
    at org.apache.coyote.ajp.AjpProcessor.process(AjpProcessor.java:436)
    at org.apache.coyote.ajp.AjpProtocol$AjpConnectionHandler.process(AjpProtocol.java:384)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$Worker.run(JIoEndpoint.java:447)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:619)
Caused by: java.io.IOException: Request data cannot be read
    at org.ajax4jsf.request.MultipartRequest.readData(MultipartRequest.java:341)
    at org.ajax4jsf.request.MultipartRequest.readNext(MultipartRequest.java:210)
    at org.ajax4jsf.request.MultipartRequest.parseRequest(MultipartRequest.java:382)
    ... 101 more
```

I am not sure if 
1. firewalls in that client network can give this problem or
2. apache / jboss configuration (req timeout etc) - but then upload works from other country networks.

Just to add a note about Richfaces fileupload component client side behavior: It is trying multiple times to upload the same file. This is evident from the progress bar, where it tries to upload some bytes, fails, again starts from the start, again fails...this pattern is also matches with apache server logs as shown below. Finally, after 5-10 tries, upload fails with "Transfer error occurred".

```
x.x.x.x - - - [09/Sep/2012:13:51:52 -0400] "POST /myapp/ui/home.faces HTTP/1.1" 200 4986

x.x.x.x - - - [09/Sep/2012:13:50:59 -0400] "POST /myapp
/ui/home.faces?_richfaces_upload_uid=0.21159051128917716&
actionForm:upload=actionForm:upload&_richfaces_upload_file_indicator=true&
AJAXREQUEST=actionForm:j_id437 HTTP/1.1" 200 -

x.x.x.x - - - [09/Sep/2012:13:51:53 -0400] "POST /myapp/ui/home.faces HTTP/1.1" 200 4984
x.x.x.x - - - [09/Sep/2012:13:51:55 -0400] "POST /myapp/ui/home.faces HTTP/1.1" 200 4984
x.x.x.x -- - [09/Sep/2012:13:51:56 -0400] "POST /myapp/ui/home.faces HTTP/1.1" 200 4984
x.x.x.x - - - [09/Sep/2012:13:51:57 -0400] "POST /myapp/ui/home.faces HTTP/1.1" 200 4984
x.x.x.x - - - [09/Sep/2012:13:51:58 -0400] "POST /myapp/ui/home.faces HTTP/1.1" 200 4984
x.x.x.x - - - [09/Sep/2012:13:51:59 -0400] "POST /myapp/ui/home.faces HTTP/1.1" 200 4984
x.x.x.x - - - [09/Sep/2012:13:52:00 -0400] "POST /myapp/ui/home.faces HTTP/1.1" 200 4984
x.x.x.x - - - [09/Sep/2012:13:52:01 -0400] "POST /myapp/ui/home.faces HTTP/1.1" 200 4984
x.x.x.x - - - [09/Sep/2012:13:52:02 -0400] "POST /myapp/ui/home.faces HTTP/1.1" 200 4984
x.x.x.x - - - [09/Sep/2012:13:52:04 -0400] "POST /myapp/ui/home.faces HTTP/1.1" 200 4984
x.x.x.x - - - [09/Sep/2012:13:52:05 -0400] "POST /myapp/ui/home.faces HTTP/1.1" 200 4984
x.x.x.x - - - [09/Sep/2012:13:52:06 -0400] "POST /myapp/ui/home.faces HTTP/1.1" 200 4984
x.x.x.x - - - [09/Sep/2012:13:52:07 -0400] "POST /myapp/ui/home.faces HTTP/1.1" 200 4984
x.x.x.x - - - [09/Sep/2012:13:52:08 -0400] "POST /myapp/ui/home.faces HTTP/1.1" 200 4984
x.x.x.x - - - [09/Sep/2012:13:52:09 -0400] "POST /myapp/ui/home.faces HTTP/1.1" 200 4984
x.x.x.x - - - [09/Sep/2012:13:52:10 -0400] "POST /myapp/ui/home.faces HTTP/1.1" 200 4984
x.x.x.x - - - [09/Sep/2012:13:52:12 -0400] "POST /myapp/ui/home.faces HTTP/1.1" 200 4984
x.x.x.x - - - [09/Sep/2012:13:52:13 -0400] "POST /myapp/ui/home.faces HTTP/1.1" 200 4984
x.x.x.x - - - [09/Sep/2012:13:52:14 -0400] "POST /myapp/ui/home.faces HTTP/1.1" 200 4984
x.x.x.x - - - [09/Sep/2012:13:52:15 -0400] "POST /myapp/ui/home.faces HTTP/1.1" 200 4984
x.x.x.x - - - [09/Sep/2012:13:52:16 -0400] "POST /myapp/ui/home.faces HTTP/1.1" 200 4984

x.x.x.x - - - [09/Sep/2012:13:51:53 -0400] "POST /myapp
/ui/home.faces?_richfaces_upload_uid=0.21159051128917716&
actionForm:upload=actionForm:upload&_richfaces_upload_file_indicator=true&
AJAXREQUEST=actionForm:j_id437 HTTP/1.1" 200 -

x.x.x.x - - - [09/Sep/2012:13:52:17 -0400] "POST /myapp/ui/home.faces HTTP/1.1" 200 4984
x.x.x.x - - - [09/Sep/2012:13:52:18 -0400] "POST /myapp/ui/home.faces HTTP/1.1" 200 4984
x.x.x.x - - - [09/Sep/2012:13:52:19 -0400] "POST /myapp/ui/home.faces HTTP/1.1" 200 4984
x.x.x.x -- - [09/Sep/2012:13:52:21 -0400] "POST /myapp/ui/home.faces HTTP/1.1" 200 4984
x.x.x.x - - - [09/Sep/2012:13:52:22 -0400] "POST /myapp/ui/home.faces HTTP/1.1" 200 4984
x.x.x.x -- - [09/Sep/2012:13:52:23 -0400] "POST /myapp/ui/home.faces HTTP/1.1" 200 4984
x.x.x.x - - - [09/Sep/2012:13:52:24 -0400] "POST /myapp/ui/home.faces HTTP/1.1" 200 4984
x.x.x.x - - - [09/Sep/2012:13:52:25 -0400] "POST /myapp/ui/home.faces HTTP/1.1" 200 4984
x.x.x.x - - - [09/Sep/2012:13:52:26 -0400] "POST /myapp/ui/home.faces HTTP/1.1" 200 4984
x.x.x.x - - - [09/Sep/2012:13:52:27 -0400] "POST /myapp/ui/home.faces HTTP/1.1" 200 4984
x.x.x.x - - - [09/Sep/2012:13:52:29 -0400] "POST /myapp/ui/home.faces HTTP/1.1" 200 4984
x.x.x.x - - - [09/Sep/2012:13:52:30 -0400] "POST /myapp/ui/home.faces HTTP/1.1" 200 4984
x.x.x.x - - - [09/Sep/2012:13:52:31 -0400] "POST /myapp/ui/home.faces HTTP/1.1" 200 4984
x.x.x.x - - - [09/Sep/2012:13:52:32 -0400] "POST /myapp/ui/home.faces HTTP/1.1" 200 4984
x.x.x.x - - - [09/Sep/2012:13:52:33 -0400] "POST /myapp/ui/home.faces HTTP/1.1" 200 4984
x.x.x.x - - - [09/Sep/2012:13:52:34 -0400] "POST /myapp/ui/home.faces HTTP/1.1" 200 4984
x.x.x.x - - - [09/Sep/2012:13:52:35 -0400] "POST /myapp/ui/home.faces HTTP/1.1" 200 4984
x.x.x.x - - - [09/Sep/2012:13:52:37 -0400] "POST /myapp/ui/home.faces HTTP/1.1" 200 4984
x.x.x.x - - - [09/Sep/2012:13:52:38 -0400] "POST /myapp/ui/home.faces HTTP/1.1" 200 4984

x.x.x.x -- - [09/Sep/2012:13:52:16 -0400] "POST /myapp
/ui/home.faces?_richfaces_upload_uid=0.21159051128917716&
actionForm:upload=actionForm:upload&_richfaces_upload_file_indicator=true&
AJAXREQUEST=actionForm:j_id437 HTTP/1.1" 200 -

x.x.x.x - - - [09/Sep/2012:13:52:39 -0400] "POST /myapp/ui/home.faces HTTP/1.1" 200 4984
x.x.x.x - - [09/Sep/2012:13:52:40 -0400] "POST /myapp/ui/home.faces HTTP/1.1" 200 4984
```

Please share any pointers or workarounds that I can try, and that will be very helpful.

**@update** : After running apache with debug logs, the error log shows the upload for a single file of size 200MB. In this case, **5 tries** happened to upload, in each try, the error message is

> [client x.x.x.x] (OS 10054)An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host.  : core_output_filter: writing data to the network

, but finally upload failed. Please share any idea where to fix this issue.

```
[Thu Sep 13 01:52:54 2012] [info] removed PID file C:/Program Files (x86)/Apache Software Foundation/Apache2.2/logs/httpd.pid (pid=8060)
[Thu Sep 13 01:55:57 2012] [notice] Apache/2.2.22 (Win32) mod_jk/1.2.31 configured -- resuming normal operations
.
.
.
[Thu Sep 13 01:55:57 2012] [notice] Child 7864: Acquired the start mutex.
[Thu Sep 13 01:55:57 2012] [notice] Child 7864: Starting 64 worker threads.
[Thu Sep 13 01:55:57 2012] [notice] Child 7864: Starting thread to listen on port 80.
[Thu Sep 13 01:58:19 2012] [info] [client x.x.x.x] (OS 10054)An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host.  : core_output_filter: writing data to the network
[Thu Sep 13 02:00:45 2012] [info] [client x.x.x.x] (OS 10054)An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host.  : core_output_filter: writing data to the network
[Thu Sep 13 02:01:20 2012] [info] [client x.x.x.x] (OS 10054)An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host.  : core_output_filter: writing data to the network
[Thu Sep 13 02:02:10 2012] [info] [client x.x.x.x] (OS 10054)An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host.  : core_output_filter: writing data to the network
[Thu Sep 13 02:02:47 2012] [info] [client x.x.x.x] (OS 10054)An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host.  : core_output_filter: writing data to the network
[Thu Sep 13 02:03:19 2012] [info] [client x.x.x.x] (OS 10054)An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host.  : core_output_filter: writing data to the network
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the following solution, hope it helps someone. Thanks very much all for your replies.

With port 80 and HTTP, the file transfers are being stopped by web/URL filtering appliances. 
The solution is to change the HTTP based portal from port 80 to 8080.

Or if the site is to be run on port 80, change the site to secure (https)

Answer (score 0):

We don't use `richfaces` but `trinidad` which is another JSF component library.

There is a configuration which defines the files size which can be uploaded as follows:

```
<context-param>
    <!-- Maximum disk space per request (in bytes) -->
    <param-name>org.apache.myfaces.trinidad.UPLOAD_MAX_DISK_SPACE</param-name>
    <!-- Use 5,000K -->
    <param-value>15360000</param-value>
</context-param>
```

Here you can specify how large file you can support. **Look for similar configuration for `richfaces` as well.**

Comment: Neither RichFaces nor Trinidad are JSF implementations. They are JSF component libraries.